# Get photos of an event wall on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to do something that seems really simple when you take a look to the graph API doc on facebook developper web site : get the photos that have been posted on an event wall !
However everytime I try to do this request (a GET request on //photos) the only thing I get is an empty "data" array. And yes I have the permissions that are asked by Facebook...

Is it a part of the API that is not working ? (Please if there is guy from Facebook around here...) or is it me ?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You have the correct event_id and permissions (user_events)

Comment: I have the correct event id (I have event tried with multiple differents events, each having photos on their wall) et I have also the right persmissions.

Comment: You can try yourself on the graph explorer for an event, and you're going to see that all the results for photos are empty...

Comment: +1 the ques, since I've never seen such problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `/event-id/photos` didn't worked (yet mentioned in the docs); but there's a way (full-proof)-

```
<event-id>/feed?fields=picture
```

You'll get an array in result; for each object if `picture` object is available or not.

I think this is the only solution, since if you open your event nowhere you can find the thing such as "event photos". The photos published by the users on an event are just a feed, there's no album(s) created.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sahil for your help, however this solution only returns the thumbnail (picture) of the first photo of each post. For example if a user post 10 photos at the same time I will only have the first one and in a very very low quality !
It really seems that Facebook is having an issue with this part of their graph API !

Comment: aah! yes, seems to be some bug